# Kendo treelist display custom message for "No records to display"

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-treelist

I have created kendo-treelist in angularjs.

Initially I am passing empty data so it is showing "No records to display". I want to customize this message. How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the `messages.noRows` property

```
<div id="treeList"></div>
<script>
  $("#treeList").kendoTreeList({
    dataSource: [],
    columns: [ "name", "age" ],
    messages: {
      noRows: "No data"
    }
  });
</script>
```

API Documentation can be found here https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treelist/configuration/messages.norows